# How to use getGuestList to get Names, not email addresses?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've found this script (posted by Jonathon), and need to modify it to provide user names.

When I try to get the guest names (using `getGuestList()`) it returns EventGuest in my spreadsheet.

How can I get the guest names (not emails) into the spreadsheet?

```
function caltest3(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( 'spreadsheetId' ),
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName( 'sheetName' ),
  cals = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], c, cal, calName,
  start = new Date( 'whenever' ), end = new Date( 'whenever' ),
  events, i, details,
  eventslog = [], e,
  rows = [], range;

for (c = 0; c < cals.length; c += 1) {

cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cals[c]);
calName = cal.getTitle();
events = cal.getEvents(start, end);

// add the events of the current calendar to the array of all events
  eventslog = eventslog.concat(
   events.map(function(event) {
     return {
       time: new Date(event.getStartTime()).getTime(), // sort by this
        details: [
         event.getTitle(),
         event.getStartTime(),
         event.getEndTime(),
         event.getDescription(),
         event.getLocation(),
         calName // change calendar info position in array to suit
        ]
      };
    })
  );
 }

// sort array of event so date order can be either way by reversing a & b
eventslog.sort(function(a, b) { return a.time - b.time; });

rows = eventslog.map(function(entry) { return entry.details; });

range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 6);
range.setValues(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the guests returned by `Event.getGuestList()`, and retrieve each name with `EventGuest.getName()`, [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getName%28%29). You should validate that the name isn't blank, and perhaps settle for the email in that case - I'll leave that to you.

Here's how your function would change:

```
function caltest3(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( 'spreadsheetId' ),
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName( 'sheetName' ),
  cals = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], c, cal, calName,
  start = new Date( 'whenever' ), end = new Date( 'whenever' ),
  events, i, details,
  eventslog = [], e,
  rows = [], range;

for (c = 0; c < cals.length; c += 1) {

cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cals[c]);
calName = cal.getTitle();
events = cal.getEvents(start, end);

// add the events of the current calendar to the array of all events
  eventslog = eventslog.concat(
   events.map(function(event) {
     var deets =  {
       time: new Date(event.getStartTime()).getTime(), // sort by this
        details: [
         event.getTitle(),
         event.getStartTime(),
         event.getEndTime(),
         event.getDescription(),
         event.getLocation(),
         calName // change calendar info position in array to suit
        ]
      };
      var guestList = event.getGuestList();
      event.guests = [];
      for (var i in guestList) {
        event.guests.push(guestList[i].getName());
      } 
      deets.guests = guestList;
      return deets;
    })
  );
 }
```