# Problems with Google Calendar Export and getName()

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a script as attached below. It pulls off events from a google calendar into a series of headings.

I have been hoping to integrate the `getName()` string where instead of the `getguestlist()` (row 18). I'm new to scripting and simply replacing these doesn't work.

Would anyone be able to help to let me know how I can get this working so that an individuals name (or at least email) is returned.

```js
function GoogleCalendarExport() {

  var mycal = "email@email.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 01 , 2018 00:00:00 GMT"), new Date("March 01, 2019 23:59:59 GMT"), {
    search: '-project123'
  });

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var header = [
    ["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", "Guest List", "Event Type", "Activity Category", "School/College in Attendance", "Year Group/Audience Present", "Number of Prospectus", "Approximate number in the audience if a talk", "Approximate number spoken to", "Notes"]
  ]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 22);
  range.setValues(header);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var row = i + 2;
    var myformula_placeholder = '';

    var details = [
      [mycal, events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getGustlist(), events[i].getDescription()]
    ];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 15);
    range.setValues(details);

    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 7);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' + row + ')+(MINUTE(F' + row + ')/60))-(HOUR(E' + row + ')+(MINUTE(E' + row + ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('.00');


  };

}
```

Comment: In your script, ``getGustlist()`` of ``events[i].getGustlist()`` is a spelling mistake. Please use ``getGuestList()``. And ``getGuestList()`` returns an array of ``EventGuest[]``. So for example, how about modifying from ``events[i].getGustlist()`` to ``events[i].getGuestList().map(function(e) {return e.getName()}).join(", ")``? The official document is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getguestlist).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use getGuestList to get Names, not email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167244/how-to-use-getguestlist-to-get-names-not-email-addresses)